# Page content not visible after page loading animation in Tailwind CSS / Javascript

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

As the title suggests, I am having problems implementing a simple page loading animation onto one of my projects.

**The expected outcome is:**

- *A loading animation / overlay which fades away once page finishes loading*

**The current outcome is:**

- *Overlay's opacity goes to 0 (thus hiding the loading animation), but the page content doesn't appear visible*

Here's simplified example code of a simulated page loader & some simulated page content.

```
<!-- Page Loader -->
<!-- Loader Wrapper -->
<div class="bg-blue-200 flex justify-center items-center transition-all opacity-100 ease-in-out duration-1000 h-screen" id="page-loader">
  <!-- Loader -->
  <div class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -ml-24 -mt-3">
    <p>YOUR CONTENT IS LOADING<p>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Page Content -->
<div>
  <!-- Simulated Navbar that is not visible even after page loader is done -->
  <nav class="bg-red-200 fixed w-full font-source font-extralight">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <p>LOGO<p>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Javascript for above and below examples:**

```
const loader = document.getElementById('page-loader')

// Once page is finished loading start the transition to page content. Set timeout is only used here to simulate a page load time of 3 seconds.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    setTimeout(() => { loader.classList.replace('opacity-100', 'opacity-0'); }, 3000);
})
```

I have also tried this:

```
<!-- Page Loader Wrapper -->
<div class="flex justify-center items-center opacity-100 transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000" id="page-loader">
<!-- Loader -->
  <div class="sk-cube-grid absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -ml-8 -mt-8">
    <p>YOUR CONTENT IS LOADING</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Simulated navbar which bleeds through -->
<nav class="bg-blue-200 fixed w-full">
  <div class="flex max-w-2xl mx-auto items-center bg-red-300">
    <div class="flex justify-start">
      <p>Logo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

However this doesn't work either, due to the page content "bleeding" through the page loading overlay.

Comment: I recommend that to use `display:none` is better than `opacity` in your case. :)

Comment: @JsWizard That doesn't work. The problem with using ```display-none``` in a case like this is that it has no transition, thus defeating the whole idea of a loading screen that fades away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by giving your `page-loader` div 3 new properties:

- `absolute` - This takes the div out of the normal page flow, allowing us to position it on top of the page.
- `inset-0` - This is the same as giving the div `top: 0`, `bottom: 0`, `left: 0`, `right: 0`. This essentially pins each edge of the div to the side of the page.
- `z-50` - The `z-index` of an element controls the vertical order of elements. Giving the div a `z-index` of `50` brings it to top, making it appear on top of the rest of the page.

```html
<div class="absolute inset-0 z-50 bg-blue-200 transition-all opacity-100 ease-in-out duration-1000 h-screen" id="page-loader">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5eq3po4/

Comment: Appreciate the answer, this does indeed work. Thanks. :)

I'd like to point out that when using the tailwind classes ```absolute``` & ```inset-0``` the classes ```flex```, ```justify-center``` & ```items-center``` are redundant and should be removed from the div.